# Convert varchar which represents DateTime in universal format (dd/MM/yy hh:mm) to DateTime

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I have a table with a `varchar` column which represent date and time in the next format:

```
dd/MM/yy hh:mm
```

For example: `27/01/13 07:57`

I need to convert this column to `DateTime` type.

I tried to do it without success.

Assume that `@varcharDT` contains the `VarChar` DateTime and I want insert the converted value to `@dateTimeDT` variable.

```
DECLARE @varcharDT varchar(1000)
SELECT @varcharDT = dateTimeColumn from dbo.tempTable

--Trying to convert
DECLARE @dateTimeDT DateTime
SET @dateTimeDT= CONVERT (DATETIME, @varcharDT )
```

The last line raise the next exception:

> *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

I think the conversion fails because my `VarChar` DateTime is in custom format.

How can I solve it?

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
CONVERT(datetime, @varcharDT, 3)
```

The last number is the style for the convert. The list can be found in the MSDN documentation article [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion and I get same error: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."